Tcolorbox section title - Large unwanted space
I am trying to make a section title from a tcolorbox by creating a \newcommand. I did not modify directly the section style with the titlesec package as I need to modify only some of the section titles.
I included the section number in the tcolorbox title using \numberline{\thesection.}. However, there is a very large space which includes itself between the section number and the title.
How can I avoid this space?
Note that if the \textbf{} is removed, a linebreak is included instead of a large space.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\SpecialSection}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{section}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        adjusted title=\textbf{\numberline{\thesection.}~#1}
        ]
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    \SpecialSection{Test a title}
\end{document}


\numberline is an internal part of the table of contents layout and sets text to the width of the scratch register \@tempdima which could have any arbitrary value in this context.
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}

It isn't clear what the intention is but remove \numberline which should never be in a section heading (or anywhere in the document)

If I remove \numberline from my custom section title, how do I write the section number automatically in the tcolorbox?

@AlMa ??? that is what \thesection is doing, all \numberline does is force that to be as wide as whatever random value is stored in \@tempdima at that point.  Inside the table of contents code \@tempdima is set up based on the current indentation and widths for section numbers etc and this is used to make a box of fixed width for ...... (page-number)  but here it is doing absolutely nothing useful, just delete it

Oh! Thank you! So far I was believing that \thesection would work only with a \section command. It is much clearer now.
